# State the transformations necessary (and in the proper order) to transform

Tags: linear-transformations

State the transformations necessary (and in the proper order) to transform $f(x) = 2^{(x+1)}$ to $g(x) = \frac14(2^x)$.

I got a vertical compression by a factor of $\frac14$, one unit right, and $5$ units up. Am I correct? I think the transformations are right, but is the order right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you can rewrite $g(x)$ as $g(x) = 2^{-2}(2^x)$. Then you can rewrite it further so that only one transformation is needed.

Comment: Hi sorry, I still haven't figured out if my transformations are in the right order for my case though...

Comment: Okay, start with rewriting what I have for $g(x)$. What would the rewrite be?

Comment: I kind of mean more in the sense that this is a special case where the 2 comes out like it does, I preferably need a catch-it-all type of rule where I don't consider exceptions like these ones where the vertical stretch/compression is an easy power of 2.

Comment: Well, if you arrange this correctly, there won't be a need for a vertical stretch component. :)